# Missing derivative formats which are available in A360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I've some Fusion360 models in my A360.

Inside the A360 website, I can request to download a Fusion360 file in DXF, Inventor or SketchUp (any many other) formats.

So my question is:
Why is derivating a Fusion360 file to DXF, Invetor or SketchUp supported and possible in the A360 cloud service, but not inside the Forge ModelDerivative service?

Don't need this right now, I just want to understand why the possible derivatives are not consistent across the Autodesk cloud services.

Regards,
Michael

Comment: Different products, different capabilities... at the moment you can use Model Derivative API to export F3D to DWG, FBX, IGES, OBJ, STEP, STL. You can refer to this matrix for more details about the export formats: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations. More formats may be added in the future based on customers needs/requests. So if an export format is really important to you, feel free to let us know.

Comment: Alright, thx Philippe!

Comment: @Philippe What would be very valuable for us and our future plans would be able to derivate OBJ back to F3D. 

Now we combine OBJs derived from F3Ds in an external web editor to a new combination. This can be saved as a new OBJ. But if we have to represent this new combination in an Aurodesk product like ACAD or Revit, we have to "build" it there from the "OBJs blueprint". If there would be a way to just reuse the new OBJ back in Autodesk products by being able to create a F3D out of it, that would be a huge deal for us!

Comment: @Philippe This gets especially important when it comes to 3D representation of very huge models in ACAD/Revit (stores with more than 10000 squaremeters and thousands of objects combined from much more "atomar" objects (like described in my comment above). if all these thousand objects have to be build from the single elements right in the model, this gets a serious performance issue. Having just one big "baked" combination is much more beneficial than.